# How to handle menu item selection in ExtensionContributionFactory class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to dynamically add menu items to context menu. I have a class extending ExtensionContributionFactory. I am using CompoundContributionItem to add menu items. But while I add these menu items I need to check some conditions on object for which this context menu was called.
For example if user right clicks on table row I need that clicked object for further processing to decide whether to show menu items or not. How do I achieve this.

Edit: Changed CompoundContributionFactory to CompoundContributionItem

Comment: This is a very rare way to create menu items, other than a few tests I can't find any examples of its use in Eclipse core + WTP + CDT. Defining menus using the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point in the plugin.xml the `visibleWhen` element can be used to control menu visibility.

Comment: And I can't find `CompoundContributionFactory` at all, what is that?